# Concat Operation in Google Spradsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this formuala

```
=IF(F3="","",IF(F3=K3, VLOOKUP(H3, 'Invoice 2020'!B3:C14, 2, FALSE)))
```

Now I want it in something like the below way

```
=IF(F3="","",IF(F3=K3, VLOOKUP(H3, 'Invoice 2020'!"B" & L3 & ":C" & M3, 2, FALSE)))
```

Here, I am trying to concat B with L3 and :C with M3

The reference to the sub-sheet **'Invoice 2020'** goes away as soon as I do anything like above.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just entering it as a formula in Google Sheets, you need to use Indirect:

```
=IF(F3="","",IF(F3=K3, VLOOKUP(H3, indirect("'Invoice 2020'!B"&L3&":C"&M3), 2, FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the tags you added to the question, I assume you are open to using Google Apps Script to accomplish this. In such case, what about using this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var invoice = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice 2020");
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destCell = sheet1.getRange(3, 1); // Change accordingly
  var rowIndex = 3;
  var f3 = sheet1.getRange(rowIndex, 6).getValue();
  if (f3 == "") {    
    destCell.setValue("");
    return;
  }
  var k3 = sheet1.getRange(rowIndex, 11).getValue();
  if (f3 == k3) {
    var h3 = sheet1.getRange(rowIndex, 8).getValue();
    var l3 = sheet1.getRange(rowIndex, 12).getValue();
    var m3 = sheet1.getRange(rowIndex, 13).getValue();
    var numRows = m3 - l3 + 1; 
    var lookup = invoice.getRange(l3, 2, numRows, 2).getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++) {
      if (lookup[i][0] == h3) {
        destCell.setValue(lookup[i][1]);
        return;
      }
    }    
    destCell.setValue("");
  }
}
```

This function gets trigged every time the spreadsheet is edited and does the following:

- Defines a cell where results will be written to, defined as `destCell` (in this example, such cell is `A3` from `Sheet1`, please change this according to your preferences).
- Checks if cell `F3` of `Sheet1` is empty, if that's the case, `A3` becomes empty.
- Checks if `F3` is equal to `K3`. If that's the case, it looks at sheet `Invoice 2020` for a range (columns B and C and rows defined by the values in `L3` and `M3` from `Sheet1`).
- If it finds a value in column B that matches `H3` from `Sheet1`, it writes the corresponding value from column C to `A3`. Otherwise, `A3` becomes empty.

This is done via an [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) but it could be modified to make this a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). Whatever suits you.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: but it fails to account for static changes. though an elegant solution. thanks a ton.